# Problema al migrar GXFlow GX16 a GX17

Tags: genexus

¿Qué tal?

Estamos migrando una KB Java-MySQL GX16 U6 a GX17U7 y al migrar las tablas de workflow, obtenemos el siguiente error:

> Error Inconsistent process metadata detected in PWFImpact
> Verify that the conversion procedure PWFXE3R3 was executed correctly

Estos son los pasos que seguimos para la migración:

1. En GX17U7 creamos una KB nueva desde GXServer, esta KB está en GX16U6.
2. Configuramos el datastore Default para que apunte a una copia de la base de datos de producción.
3. Copiamos todos los User Controls que se usan en la KB desde la instalación de GX16U6 a la de GX17U7.
4. Hicimos un Build All, las tablas de GAM se actualizaron correctamente de la versión 4.0.4 a la versión 4.0.5, las tablas de GXFlow también se actualizaron correctamente de la versión 16.0.6 a la 16.0.7.
5. Al momento de desplegar los Business Processes muestra el error descrito arriba, desde Tools > Workflow > Deploy Business Processes también nos da el mismo error al intentar desplegar cualquier proceso.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Desde ya muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que el problema puede ser dos cosas:

**1. No tenés actualizado el runtime de GXflow.**

Con GX se distribuyen algunos por defecto pero Java/MySQL no.
Lo podés obtener de https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/downloadcenter?data=5939

En particular el archivo que gobierna la ejecución de la actualización es el "ReorgsDescriptor.xml" (ejemplo: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u7\Packages\Gxpm\Platforms\javamysql5\ReorgsDescriptor.xml)

**2. La versión de los datos de la DB de GXflow no es correcta**

La actualización toma en cuenta la versión que tiene la DB y cómo llegar a la nueva (ejecuta reorgs sucesivas) en base al archivo que mencioné antes.

Ahi es importante ver el output completo, en particular la parte que dice algo como:

```
========== Retrieve Workflow Runtime Version From Database started ==========
Current version: 16.8.00
Success: Retrieve Workflow Runtime Version From Database
```